# error unlisting result of lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have run a lapply like:

```
paper_author_name<-lapply(train_author,function(x){  
as.data.frame(paper_author$author_name[which(paper_author$author_id%in%x)])
})
```

I am getting result as:

```
 [[1]]
paper_author$author_name[which(paper_author$author_id %in% x)]
                                             Emanuele Buratti
                                             Emanuele Buratti
                                             Abdiub bahir
```

Now i need to unlist this result by

```
unlist(paper_author_name[1])
```

But I am getting error

```
Error in structure(res, levels = lv, names = nm, class = "factor") : 
'names' attribute [135] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

How could I now unlist the result.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have your function return data.frames? What does your expected result look like?

Comment: @Roland-yes there shouldn't have been a data frame, but now I have the output how can i unlist the output

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, paper_author_name)`, but you probably don't have to use `lapply` at all.